# Use pymssql to write to CSV and use column names as headers

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv, pymssql

I have the below script for i) connecting to a DB, ii) running a query, iii) saving the results of the query as a csv and iv) emailing the output.

It all works fine, except I can't seem to get the column names as headers on the file. I've trawled through SO, but can't find a solution that works for me. My script is as follows. Any help would be great:

```
import pymssql
import csv
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email import encoders
fromaddr='XXXX@gmail.com'
toaddr='XXXX@gmail.com'
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Subject'] = "This is a test"
body = "This is still a test"
conn = pymssql.connect(server='XXXXXXXXXX.net',
               port=XXXX,
               user='XXXX',
               password='XXXX',
               database='XXXX')
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = 'Select * From Table'
cursor.execute(query)
with open("XXXXXXXX.csv","w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    for row in cursor:
        writer.writerow(row)
msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))
filename = "XXXXXX.csv"
attachment = open("XXXXXXXXXXX.csv","rb")
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment; filename= %s" % filename)
msg.attach(part)
text = msg.as_string()
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com',587)
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr,"XXXXXX")
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr,toaddr,text)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [DB-API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#description) -- to which [PyMSSQL complies](http://pymssql.org/en/stable/pymssql_examples.html#basic-features-strict-db-api-compliance) -- there is a cursor attribute called `.description` which you can use here.

```
with open("XXXXXXXX.csv","w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    writer.writerow(col[0] for col in cursor.description)
    for row in cursor:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: you can also `writer.writerows(cursor)` instead of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.description` on the `cursor` object to and loop through it to get the names of the column like:

```
colNameList = []
for i in range(len(cursor.description)):
    desc = cursor.description[i]
    colNameList.append(desc[0])

    colNames = ','.join(colNameList)
    print colNames
```